# The Eyeball Theorem generalized

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have not seen the [2D Eyeball Theorem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheEyeballTheorem/)—that tangents from the centers of two circles, each encompassing the other, intersect each circle in the same segment length—generalized to higher dimensions. It generalizes easily: the radius of the circles of cone/sphere intersections in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (below, red) are equal:

   [image: EyeBall]
What I am wondering is if there is a sense in which some form of
this theorem generalizes to other
objects: axis-aligned cubes, ellipsoids, or other shapes. Or does the theorem in some
sense characterize spheres? If anyone has seen this addressed previously, I'd appreciate a pointer. Thanks!

---

(*Added*). This seems to work for squares/cubes:

   [image: EyeSquare]

Comment: I think I would have enjoyed this image *much* more had I not read "eyeball theorem" in the title!

Comment: And I would probably not have opened the question without the eyeball reference in the title! That is lovely, the theorem (in the plane) and the image.

Comment: Does the 2D version have any generalizations?

Comment: @BenjaminYoung: That is the place to start. I don't know...

Comment: Of course this also works for axis-aligned ellipses of the same eccentricity.

Comment: One generalization to squares fails. If you consider the lines connecting the centers of the squares to the visible corners of the other square, these don't have the same size "arcs." For example, axis-aligned squares of sides $2$ and $4$ whose centers are distance $10$ apart in the direction of an axis produce arcs of sizes $4/9$ and $1/2$. Your diagram for squares shows secant lines from the centers of squares to the centers of sides, not to the corners that I think would be analogues of tangent lines.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Yes, my "generalization" for the square only succeeds by changing the tangent to a secant.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if we rotate the squares $45$ degrees.

Comment: Well, for a rotationally symmetric 3D configuration the result is equivalent to the 2D configuration obtained by intersecting with the plane containing the axis, so the quest is for 2D objects, I guess. Did you try Reuleaux triangles? Because of constant diameter it's possible that the theorem would hold regardless of their relative orientation, leading to a non-symmetric configuration. Ditto Reuleaux tetrahedrons.

Comment: @Michael: Good idea to explore constant-width bodies.

Comment: Trying to interpolate between circles and squares, 
I tried with curves of the type $(r^d-x^d)^{1/d}$ but this does not work with the "obvious" generalization.

Comment: Dear Dr. @JosephO'Rourke Please help me comment at here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250730/a-generalization-of-the-british-flag-theorem-in-euclidean-three-space

Thank to You very much

Comment: Dear Dr. @Michael Please help me comment at here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250730/a-generalization-of-the-british-flag-theorem-in-euclidean-three-space

Thank to You very much

Comment: My intuition is that this eyeball theorem can be seen as a particular case of the conservation of [étendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) in geometrical optics, but I haven't been able to see precisely how.

Answer (score 2):

I have introduced some variants of the Eyeball theorem and also seems to admit generalizations in 3D. And as if that were not enough the Archimedean twins have been brought together with these theorems. See link below

http://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2014/03/praying-eyes-theorem.html

Comment: And you have posted a related question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191719/the-praying-eyes-theorem-generalized