# Is the conjecture true for n-sphere $(n>2)$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces

This is higher dimension conjecture of **Problem 3845 in Crux Mathematicorum** and Theorem 2 in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10345.pdf):

PS: This figure is very nice, this is also generalization of Brianchon’s theorem, The Pascal theorem, the Seven circle theorem...etc..... with higher dimension (These are some very nice theorems in plane Geometry). But I don’t know why some one vote down?

I don’t think this question is not good than:

[Does this geometry theorem have a name?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284458/does-this-geometry-theorem-have-a-name)

[The Eyeball Theorem generalized](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152192/the-eyeball-theorem-generalized)

But the questions above have many vote up. But why some one vote down my question?

> > **My question:** The conjecure as follows true for $2$-sphere. Is the conjecture true for n-sphere $(n>2)$?

**Conjecture:** Let two circle $(C_1)$, $(C_2)$ on n-sphere $(O)$. Let $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ be six arbitrary points in $(C_1)$. Let $1'$ be arbitrary point in $(C_2)$. The circle $(121')$ meets $(C_2)$ at point $2'$. The circle $(232')$ meets $(C_2)$ again at $3'$, define points $4', 5', 6'$ similarly. Let $P_1, P_2, \cdots, P_6 $ are the center of circles $i{i+1}{i+1}'i'$ for $i=1, 2, \cdots, 6$. Are three planes $(P_1P_4O)$, $(P_2P_5O)$, $(P_3P_6O)$ share the same line ?

- Circles $(P_1)=(122'1')$, $(P_4)=(455'4')$ are yellow.
- Circles $(P_2)=(233'2')$, $(P_5)=(566'5')$ are green.
- Circles $(P_3)=(344'3')$, $(P_6)=(611'6')$ are blue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This figure is very nice, this is also Brianchon’s theorem with higher dimension. But I don’t known why some one vote down

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing people consider your question too elementary for this site. (Whether the picture looks nice doesn't really affect that.)

Comment: @JimConant I don’t think this question is good but many vote up https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284458/does-this-geometry-theorem-have-a-name

Comment: And I don’t thinks this question is good. But many vote up. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152192/the-eyeball-theorem-generalized

Comment: On the $n$-sphere with $n > 2$, if two circles meet at a point, then they don't necessarily meet at another point. The question seems to be not well-prepared. I vote to close.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Oh?? With n=2 we can replace 8 circles by 8 planes the result is exactly same.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question, Dao.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This question is not well-come at here. So I want deleted the question. I want send it to AMM

Comment: @GerryMyerson This question is very nice with me. There are one hundred corollary, special case of this theorem. So I want deleted this to poist on AMM

Comment: You got (and accepted) an answer. Deleting the question is vandalism. Please stop it.

Comment: Deleting the contents of a question is against site policy. You can delete your question if you have not received an answer with positive net score, but otherwise you can't deface a question. Besides, the person who answered put work into the answer; please have some respect for that, and move on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understand the construction, everything happens in the $3$-dimensional affine space spanned by the circle $C_1$ and the point $1'$. (In particular, $C_2$ has to lie in this space or the points $2',\dots,6'$ won't exist.) Since everything is also on the surface of an $n$-sphere, we can confine attention to the intersection of the affine $3$-space and the sphere, which is a $2$-sphere.  So the general case reduces to the case of the $2$-sphere.

Comment: And for the two-sphere it is obvious: they touch the ellipse with foci at centers of circles $(C_1)$ and $(C_2)$. For the proof your just need to check that perpendicular bisectors to $11'$ and $22'$ forms equal angles with $P_1C_1$ and $P_1C_2$.

Comment: This figure is very nice, this is also Brianchon’s theorem with higher dimension. But I don’t known why some one vote down

Comment: @ArseniyAkopyan Thank You very much for your answer. But can You delete your answer ? Because I don't wan this theorem are not welcome at here. I want delete my question.

Comment: @ArseniyAkopyan **This question is very nice with me. There are one hundred corollary, special case of this theorem. But this question is not welcome at here. So I want deleted the question to posed on AMM** Please help me delete